# Raspberry Pi python on startup

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to run my python script in the background on boot. This use to work all the time for me when i wanted to run my code but now it seems to not be working. I think im running NOOBS.

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh -e

sudo python /home/pi/Firebase.py &


exit 0
```

Firebase.py

```
from firebase import firebase
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://raspberrypi-5c0ce.firebaseio.com/', authentication = None)


#result = firebase.put('/light_switch','state', 'off')

#currentState = firebase.get('/light_switch', 'state')
#print(currentState)



#Initialize gpio settings
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

#Initialize gpio board
input1 = 26
input2 = 19


#setup led color with gpio setup
GPIO.setup(input1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(input2, GPIO.OUT)
#GPIO.setup(yellowLed, GPIO.OUT)

#output actual color of led based on variableColor and 1 for tru
while True:
    currentState = firebase.get('/light_switch', 'state')
#print(currentState)
    if currentState == "on":
        GPIO.output(input1, 1)
        GPIO.output(input2, 1)
    #print("on")
    else:
        GPIO.output(input1, 0)
        GPIO.output(input1, 0)
    #print("off")
```

Comment: NOOBS isn't the OS, by the way. It's Rasbian. But unclear what the `Firebase.py` contains here (or why it needs `sudo`) so it's hard to help

Comment: Ok I added the code but everything works perfectly when i run the code by default i just can get it to work in rc.local on boot.

Comment: By the name of your application I noticed that you are working with FireBase, this service requires access to the internet, but access may be delayed, so there is probably an exception and if you do not process correctly your program will start but will be closed by that exception.

Comment: Does the code run outside of `rc.local`?

Comment: yes the code works perfectly out side of rc.local

Comment: i wrote an app in swift that communicates with my pi perfectly when the program is running outside of rc.local. But it doesnt work INSIDE rc.local

Comment: im very surprised nobody has an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem needed to but a sleep so it could connect to wifi.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# Print the IP address
# Sleep introduced to see if Wifi acquired and IP assigned
date >> /tmp/rc_local_b4_sleep
sleep 15
date >> /tmp/rc_local_after_sleep

_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

/sbin/ifconfig > /tmp/network_at_boot

python /home/pi/Firebase.py &


exit 0
```